# asp.net mvc with .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0

Ok...

I am currently upgrading a project from asp.net 3.5 using asp.net mvc 2.0.

Im having a number of issues regarding namespace conflicts and other such lovely stuff.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on a few things...

1. The system.web.routing 4.0 and system.web.abstractions 4.0 libraries are empty, what's the motivation here?
2. The system.web 4.0 library isnt in the GAC, and has all the namespaces from the routing and abstractions library, how are we meant to be referencing system.web 4.0?
3. Has anyone recompiled asp.net mvc against 4.0 yet?

Cheers (and frustrated)

Byron

Answer (score 0):

We upgraded our projects from MVC1 to the 4.0 release with virtually no issues.

It sounds like something might be wrong with your 4.0 installation.  I've got System.Web 4.0.0.0 installed in both `c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32` and `c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64` on Windows 7.